# SolSpace friends secure_action

Tags: solspace, solspace-friends

Is there a way to secure the Friends forms?

I use ssl for the members section and friends is used there as well. 
All friends forms are giving me the non-secure message when trying to submit...

I have tried several options, none of them works. 
Almost thinking to alter the module code to force, only use, ssl

```
{exp:friends:message_folder_form 
return="{current_url}" 
form_class="form-horizontal" 
form_id="accounForm" 
secure_action="yes"  
secure_return="yes"}

<input type="hidden" name="secure_action" value="yes">
<input type="hidden" name="secure_return" value="yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature isn't available as of this writing.

I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

As a workaround for now, you could hard-code an `https://` URL in the `return=""` parameter to replace the non-existent secure_return="yes" parameter functionality, and use javascript/jQuery to change the `<form>`'s action="" attribute to contain `https://` instead of `http://`.

Alternatively for both cases, you could use the protocol-agnostic `//` instead as al alternative. Eg. use `return="//mysite.com/etc"` and use javascript/jQuery to change the action="" `<form>` attribute to `action="//mysite.com/etc"`. This would cover both http and https cases.

Comment: Ah ok, but this gives me some messages as well, forms that are not send secure. Is there a way to alter the friends code. All used friend forms need to be secure....

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? If the return parameter is https, and the form's action="" attribute is https (or both are using `//` instead), then what else is missing?

Comment: Using //www. in the return variable. still does give me the ! mark in the secure icon, instead of the lock. So when I want, for example, edit a folder (exp:friends:message_folder_form) I get a security warning. Form RET and action are still http://. That's why I want to hard code the https into friends. While friends is being used only in a secured environment. All other elements like, css, java and other modules/extensions are working, even Users module, in the secure environment. Except Friends. Altering the site_url into //www. is not an option

Comment: Everything on a page indeed needs to be https for that "lock icon" to display. You would have to use javascript/jQuery to change the RET url to https as well for now. Alternatively, since RET is generated using EE's `fetch_current_uri` function, I would try having the URL of the page with `{exp:friends:message_folder_form}` code be https, which should have RET be https as well. Finally, I would file a Feature Request at http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions